# Delete vertices from a graph with igraph but maintaining their original names

Tags: r, graph, igraph

With the following code

```
library('igraph')
g <- barabasi.game(10,directed=FALSE)
```

I obtained the graph depicted in the picture:
[image]
Suppose I wanted to remove the vertex `1`. In this case, I would expect a picture like this:
[image]
which I produced manually. But, if I apply the code

```
 g<-delete_vertices(g, 1)
```

I instead obtain the graph:
[image]
where the number of each vertex has been modified. How can I maintain the original number of each vertex?

Comment: you can add vertex names prior to deletion `vertex_attr(g) <- list(name = 1:10)`

Comment: @user20650 Would you write that up as a short answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retain names if you explicitly add vertex names prior to the deletion

```
vertex_attr(g) <- list(name = 1:10)
```